# querying multiple tables outputs duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

I have an ajax search engine.  If none of the filters are on, I want to query titles from every table.  In this example, there are only two tables.  music_page AND restaurant_page.

```
public function Any_Category_Name($search_title) {

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT music_page.title AS music_title, 
                                             restaurant_page.title AS restaurant_title
                                      FROM music_page,
                                           restaurant_page
                                      WHERE music_page.title 
                                            LIKE '%$search_title%' OR
                                              restaurant_page.title
                                              LIKE '%$search_title%'");
                while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $music_title = $fetch['music_title'];
                    $restaurant_title = $fetch['restaurant_title'];
                    echo '<b>Restaurant:</b> '.$restaurant_title.'<br />';
                    echo '<b>Music Spot:</b> '.$music_title.'<br />';
                    }

                }
```

This is the output when you enter a letter / search:

```
Restaurant: Giordanoes
Music Spot: jazz showcase
Restaurant: Giordanoes
Music Spot: The Green Mill
Restaurant: Giordanoes
Music Spot: ayooooo
Restaurant: Giordanoes
Music Spot: ayoooooooo
Restaurant: Giordanoes
Music Spot: new one
```

Giordanoes is the only row in restaurant_page table.  It's outputted for every row that's in music_page.  How can I remedy this?

Comment: You're JOINing two tables (music_page and restaurant_page) together and table music_page has a many to one relationship to table restaurant_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // Create the listing array
    $listing[$fetch['restaurant_title']] = array($fetch['music_title'] => 'music_title');
}

// Check if we have Restaurants
if(is_array($listing)) {
    // Loop through the new listings array
    foreach($listing as $restaurant_title => $music_titles) {
        echo '<b>Restaurant:</b> '.$restaurant_title.'<br />';

        // Check if we have Music
        if(is_array($music_titles)) {
            // Loop through the Music
            foreach($music_titles as $music_title => $placeholder) {
                echo '<b>Music Spot:</b> '.$music_title.'<br />';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<b>Music Spot:</b> No Music found<br />'; 
        }            
    }
} else {
    echo '<b>Restaurant:</b> No Restaurants found<br />';
}
```

Comment: That works.  But, it says invalid argument in foreach IF there's no results.  Also, it only outputs one result for each page.

Comment: Awesome thanks Phil.  It no longer gives the foreach error.  But, it still only outputs one result for music and restaurants.  It should be multiple for music.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into ways of properly joining your tables. As you have it, you will get a record from the `restaurant_page` table for every record in the `music_page` table.

I recommend [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

An alternative is to have two queries, each selecting records from a separate table, and two while loops to output the results, one after another.

Comment: W3Schools is a terrible website that shouldn't be used as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what happens when you join tables. what I usually do is just as you loop through, only output the restaurant if it changes from the last loop. like:

```
$last = '';
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $music_title = $fetch['music_title'];
    $restaurant_title = $fetch['restaurant_title'];
    if($last != $restaurant_title){
        echo '<h1>Restaurant: '.$restaurant_title.'</h1>';
    }
    echo '<b>Music Spot:</b> '.$music_title.'<br />';
    $last = $restaurant_title;
}
```

Comment: doh! fixed it, even if a little late.